# Another "Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)"

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran95

I'm trying to compile some code with Fortran 95 but get the following error:

```
 f(3,mx+1) = (f(1,mx+1)/(gamma1-1d0))*(0.25d0*(4d0&                
                                                   1
 Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

I thought it was a line continuation problem, so I tried to fix it by including the "&" symbol at the end of each line to continue to the next:

```
f(3,mx+1) = (f(1,mx+1)/(gamma1-1d0))*(0.25d0*(4d0&
 +rhow*(gamma21*f(2,mx+1)**2 + gamma21*f(2,mx+1)&
 + gamma21*0.25d0)+ sqrt(rhow)*(f(2,mx+1)&
 + 0.5d0)*(rhow*(f(2,mx+1)**2 + f(2,mx+1)&
 + 0.25d0) + rhow*(gamma21**2)*(f(2,mx+1)**2 + f(2,mx+1)&
 + 0.25d0) + gamma21*sqrt(16d0 + 2d0*rhow*f(2,mx+1)**2&
 + 2d0*rhow*f(2,mx+1) + 0.5d0*rhow)))) + 0.5d0*(f(2,mx+1)**2)

 f(3,mx+2) = 6*f(3,mx) - 8*f(3,mx-1) + 3*f(3,mx-2)
```

but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That snippet compiles fine for me, which makes me suspicious that your compiler might be treating it as fixed-form source, in which case the trailing `&` is not the right way to continue lines.  But without knowing how you are compiling it is difficult to do more than guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I am compiling from the command line with the following command:

      f95 -o KTscheme KTscheme.F

where KTscheme is the name of the whole file.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were correct! In fixed form, any character except 0 or a blank in column 6 of a source indicates a line continuation!

Answer (score 0):

Using the & symbol is not the correct way to continue lines in fixed-form Fortran95. In column 6 of any source line, any symbol excluding blank or 0 is a line continuation.

Comment: This raises the question of why you are using fixed-form source files unless (a) you are sending your questions through a wormhole from the 1980s or (b) you are using punched cards to prepare your programs for compilation.